# Can't open folder that was dragged and dropped to sidebar in sublime text3

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, sidebar

I recently downloaded sublime text3. To get started I dragged and dropped a folder that contained a website to the sidebar. Now I can't open the folder to get to the files. I can't drag the folder back to the desktop either. The only thing I can do is drag the folder up and down the sidebar. Yet I look a videos and see demonstrations of folders being open from the sidebar. I removed another folder of some javascript files from the sidebar and lost it, completely. I installed sidebar Enhancements and now I can see more options but I still can't do anything with the folder. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to be able to drag the folders from Sublime's sidebar back into Windows Explorer (your desktop or any folders part of Windows GUI).

When you delete files from the sidebar, they should be moved to your Recycle Bin, check to see if the files are there.

Comment: I already checked that possibility. The folder I deleted is not in the trash. I didn't actually delete it. I removed it from the project and it disappeared. When I just tried to delete a folder I go a message, 'There is no trash bin, permanent delete?'. So I didn't delete it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I removed the folder from the project and it disappeared. I couldn't delete it, couldn't open it, couldn't  move it except up and down the side bar. I had a copy of the root folder, so it wasn't a total lost. Any suggestions of what happens to files that are removed from the project in sublime text3?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe you didn't save your file? When you create a new file and type into it, the file isn't saved until you manually save it through File > Save or Ctrl-S. If you removed it before saving, your temporary file would be lost.